# Importing style in AngularJS2 using styleUrls

Tags: css, angular, styles

When I use style link in my index.html file in Angularjs2 as follows, the interface works perfectly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/path/to/css/global.css"  />
```

However, when I remove that line, and include the style directly in 'styleUrls' section of component, as follows, it does not work:

```
    @Component({
       selector: 'app-d3',
       templateUrl: './my.component.html',
       styleUrls: [
              'src/path/to/css/global.css',
       ]
    });
```

I can see that the style has been imported into the page (using style tag), but the program can not read it. I have several css files that I want to include them in this way. 
Any idea?

Comment: Try using  './src/path/to/css/global.css

Comment: @Malwaregeek I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: is your css folder on the same level as you html folders? in which case just try `./global.css` but ultimately we need to see your folder structure

Comment: @Bean0341 The css files are in /src/app/myComponent/css. From both mentioned methods, the program can see css folder, unless it raises error.

Comment: now what is the exact path of your html?

Comment: index.html is in the src folder. The component is in app folder. I can access the css through link href="src/app/myComponent/css/global.css". And inside of myComponent.ts I have: styleUrls: [  'src/path/myComponent/css/global.css',       ]

Comment: I ment your my.component.html, I am trying to get a better understanding of you folder structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138967/discussion-between-bean0341-and-enayat).

Answer (score 0):

The `styleUrls` path is relative to your component `ts` file. I think you need to go some folders up. Something like:

`styleUrls: [ '../../css/global.css`

Comment: The component folder has a folder named css. So, I should be something like this--> 'css/global.css' or './css/global.css'. Any way, it does not work if I go up.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure exactly how to help you with that as I don't have enough information about your project. I have an Angular2-starter-kit project on GitHub where I'm using stylesUrl. You may have a look at that and figure out where is your problem.
https://github.com/andreasonny83/angular2-sonny-webpack/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Otherwise, If your project is hosted on Github, just post the link and I will help you with that.

Comment: Also, have a look at the official documentation at: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#loading-styles

Comment: It has not been uploaded on Github yet. I do not think that it really depends to the structure of my project. As I mentioned, the projects is working with link tag, that follows also a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Webpack, it could be possible that you're missing the `angular2-template-loader`. Something like this:

`{
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            'awesome-typescript-loader',
            'angular2-template-loader'
          ]
        },`

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'src' from the path. Use styleUrls: ['app/myComponent/css/global.css']